# How to make an HTTPS server with Nginx in Docker for development machine?

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, https, docker-compose

How to make an HTTPS server with Nginx in Docker for the development machine.

I have tried making self-signed certificate and key and moved it up to docker container through volume and assigned it NGINX config, but it doesn't work with HTTPS but work with HTTP.

In host.conf

```
 server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/localhost.key;
    server_name localhost;
    charset utf-8;
    index index.php;
    root /var/www/html/web;
    ...
```

In docker compose

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx:
    restart: "always"
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - .certs:/etc/nginx/certs
    ports:
      - "${SERVER_PORT:-80}:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - worksite
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting for HTTPS ?

Comment: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR and the response body from the server is 0kb